# National Insurance number generator

Tags: ruby

I am trying to figure out how to DRY up this code:

```
nino = "QQ"
3.times { nino += Random.rand(10..99).to_s}
nino += ("A".."D").to_a.sample
```

I am trying to generate a sample National Insurance number starting with QQ, six digits and then ending with A, B, C or D.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why do you need the 3 times? Is there a restriction, that the first number may not be 0?

If there  is no 0-restriction, you may generate a number between 0 and 999999.
To get the leading 0 I use the `strftime`-pattern `%06i` (6 digit with leading zeros).

```
  p "QQ%06i%s" % [ Random.rand(999999), ("A".."D").to_a.sample ]
```

For the letter, you may generate a random number from 65..68 and take the character for the selected ASCII-value (code example is ruby 1.9. Maybe you need a little variation with Ruby 1.8):

```
  p "QQ%06i%s" % [ Random.rand(999999), (65 + rand(4)).chr ]
```

Answer (score 2):

As Cygal says:

> Also note that "DRY" in Code Review stands for "Don't Repeat
>   Yourself", your title is thus a bit ambiguous.

If you are repeating implementing this logic through out your code then you should dry it up.

In my opinion this code has another problem.  The purpose is not clear at a glance.  Actually, one should process it in his mind to understand what's going on.

To prevent such a problem I suggest that:

1. Encapsulate it in a method definition block with a suitable name that describes what it's doing (this way you will say what it's doing but not how it has implemented).
2. Use a pattern or format to show how the result will look like.  I am not familiar with Ruby but each language has its own way of doing it for example in C# we can use `stirng.Format` to define a format for our `string`:

   ```
   var result=String.Format("QQ{0}{1}{2}{3}",GetARandomNumber(),GetARandomNumber(),GetARandomNumber(),GetADigitBetween('A','D'));
   ```

Comment: As I responded to Cygal "Essentially my code is saying nino = blah, nino = nino + blahblah, nino = nino + blahblahblah; I am repeating myself three times which is why I was trying to not repeat myself."

Answer (score 2):

If you mean more compact code, I though you can consider this:

```
nino = "QQ"<<(10..99).to_a.sample(3)*''<<("A".."D").to_a.sample
```

Answer (score 1):

Disclaimer: I don't know Ruby but code in similar languages.

This looks "dried" enough to me. What would enhance readability though is to write this one simple line. It would show in a very explicit way that you are simply building one string (and would also make this shorter). Is it possible to make a one-liner out of this in Ruby?

Also note that "DRY" in Code Review stands for "Don't Repeat Yourself", your title is thus a bit ambiguous.

Comment: Essentially my code is saying nino = blah, nino = nino + blahblah, nino = nino + blahblahblah; I am repeating myself three times which is why I was trying to not repeat myself.

Answer (score 1):

Without leading zero's:

```
p "QQ#{rand(100_000..999_999)}#{%w(A B C D).sample}"
```

Comment: Actually in this case leading zeros were good but this would have been acceptable too. Thanks